# CentOS8 pxeboot Error setting up software source

Tags: linux, centos, pxe, kickstart

I have install PXE server last month using CentOS8-1-1911 release and it works great, i am able to PXE all my workstation but today when i update CentOS8-2-2004 with latest version and keep all kickstart options same and getting this strange error during pxe

```
Installation source (Error setting up software source)
```

[image]

I have tried to give manual URL but still same error, does anyone encounter this error in CentOS8 pxeboot ? I have also revert to Centos8-1-1911 but still same error (I have check logs and its showing correct URL in payload also i can see networking is good)

This is what i am using for installation source: http://mirror.liquidtelecom.com/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/

My kickstart file repo section

```
#
lang en_US
#
keyboard us
#
timezone America/New_York
#
zerombr
install
url             --url=http://10.40.0.20/pxe_repo/centos8-1-1911
repo            --name=centos --baseurl=http://10.40.0.20/pxe_repo/centos8-1-1911
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Resolved

CentOS8 split their installation repo so it's not just base OS, you need to add "AppStream" repo also.

```
repo    --name="AppStream" --baseurl="http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8.2.2004/AppStream/x86_64/os/"
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was setting the network before attempting to install:

```
network --bootproto=dhcp --activate --hostname=localhost.localdomain --onboot yes
```

I ran into this same issue, and attempted to try to run kickstart via inst.text to see if I could set the URL for the ISO image after the kickstart ran, but that didn't work either. I decided to move network up the chain of command if that would fix anything, and it did!

Comment: Apparently Satish already found his answer. I already had a line like that in my kickstart, so if someone else is still running into the issue I will leave this up instead of deleting it.